# Set plot height and allow the rest of the chart to resize

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display a chart as a single, horizontal column with a vertical legend below it. Here's what I have so far:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "legend": {
    "itemMarginBottom": 10
  },
  "responsive": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "condition": {
          "maxWidth": 700
        },
        "chartOptions": {
          "legend": {
            "layout": "vertical"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "bar",
    "margin": [
      0,
      0,
      44,
      0
    ]
  },
  "credits": false,
  "plotOptions": {
    "bar": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,        
        formatter() {
          let value = this.y * 100;
          return value > 4 ? `${ value.toFixed(1) }%` : null;
        },

        "overflow": "none"
      },
      "groupPadding": 0,
      "pointPadding": 0
    },
    "series": {
      "animation": false,
      "pointPadding": 0,
      "pointWidth": 40,
      "stacking": "percent",
      "events": {},
      "marker": {
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "select": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Optimized",
      "data": [
        0.7455639561796032
      ],
      "zIndex": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Partially Optimized",
      "data": [
        0.1260607930874859
      ],
      "zIndex": -1
    },
    {
      "name": "Not Optimized",
      "data": [
        0.064033328190094
      ],
      "zIndex": -2
    },
    {
      "name": "Plant Off",
      "data": [
        0.06434192254281708
      ],
      "zIndex": -3
    },
    {
      "name": "Communication Failure",
      "data": [
        0
      ],
      "zIndex": -4
    }
  ],
  "title": false,
  "tooltip": false,
  "xAxis": {
    "labels": false,
    "maxPadding": 0,
    "minPadding": 0
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "endOnTick": false,
    "labels": false,
    "maxPadding": 0,
    "min": 0,
    "minPadding": 0,
    "reversedStacks": false,
    "title": false
  }
});
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: The chart's current appearance]

The chart is responsive, and I'd really like to avoid setting a hardcoded height for the whole chart. Rather, I'd like for the plot height of the chart to be `40px`, and for Highcharts to size the height of the chart to include the remaining room for the chart's legend.

Ideally, it would look like this:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Here's a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezkkfo90/).

Answer (score 0):

You can change height of `xAxis` and `yAxis` to 40px and on each redraw event calculate optimal height for chart (top margin + height of the yAxis + bottom margin). Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6hf0ms3/